# SSRS 2008 change built-in User ID

Tags: url, reporting-services, userid

is there a way to change the value of the built-in parameter: User ID? I don't need the name of the windows authenticated user, but the name that I pass in the url to open the web page containing the report.

i.e. http://servername/ReportList/Pages/Report.aspx?username=somename

I would like that User ID = username, so I can display it in the footer of the page.

Thank you
C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the value of the built-in field but you can create a parameter, even calling it UserId or Username. (The built-in field is not really a parameter.)

Then you can assign a value to that parameter using URL Access:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx (SQL 2016 link)

> For example, to specify two parameters, “ReportMonth” and
>   “ReportYear”, defined in a report, use the following URL for a native
>   mode report server:
>
> ```
> http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
> ```
>
> For
>   example, to specify the same two parameters defined in a report, use
>   the following URL for a SharePoint integrated mode report server. Note
>   the /_vti_bin:
>
> ```
> http://myspsite/subsite/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://myspsite/subsite/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2.rdl&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
> ```

Note that you can't use URL access when running the report through the "Report Manager" interface which gives the title bar and the views to explore reports (usually at /reports/.) ReportServer is a different service that just sends the report itself.

Comment: Ok, and how can I assign the value of the parameter that I passed in the url to the created UserId? Thanks

Comment: Changed response to include link to URL access.

Comment: You can also make this parameter hidden so that the whole process is invisible to the user